# using 4.02 docker image with aws lambda try to open .usdz error

Tags: python, export, import

I am trying to use blender to convert the file type from usdz to glb. It works well in my local Mac. The script is like below

```
bpy.ops.wm.read_factory_settings(use_empty=True)
bpy.ops.wm.usd_import(filepath="usdzfile")
bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(filepath=export_file)
```

but when I using the [image](https://github.com/ranchcomputing/blender-cpu-image/pkgs/container/blender-cpu-image) with aws lambda.
The second step always went wrong. It always said that failed to open the usdz file.
Does anyone meet the same issue before?
[image]

Any comments will be appreciated.
Best,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.
It is a file path issue. The correct format is like

```
/tmp/<input_file>
```